# Animating a html table using CSS?

Tags: css, html

so im trying to make a webpage using HTML5,  i started off by making headings where the user can click to navigate the site (ie. Home, Contact, etc). I create this using a table. But what i want to do is have the table slide up and off the screen. When the user moves his/her mouse to the top, the table slides down. Unfortunately, i have no idea how i would do this as this is my 1st time programming with html and css. My current code is below if that helps:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Websites</title>

        <style>
th, td {
    padding: 15px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 120px;
}
td {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>heading 1</td>
                <td>heading 2</td>
                <td>heading 3</td>
                <td>heading 4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: DONT use tables for layout. Try using `<div>` instead

Comment: using div tag with `display:table;` as style.

Comment: how would i use div?

Answer (score 0):

Create 1 outer `<div>` with class and inside that use `<Ul> <li>` http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_lists.asp instead of table and with the help of jquery `event` you can `animate` your div Or `slideUp and slideDown`. If you search in `google` you will get lot of example. And now even with `css3` you can do `transition effect`.

Check this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a nav bar you use [ul](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_navbar.asp) and `<li>` tags :

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

and in html 5 use [nav](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp) tag (with slidedown menu) :

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
             <li><a href="index.html">Accueil</a></li>

             <li>Menu1
                 <ul>                          
                     <li><a href="page1.html">Sous-Menu1.1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="page2.html">Sous-Menu1.2</a></li>
                     <li><a href="page3.html">Sous-Menu1.3</a></li>
                  </ul>
             </li>

            <li><a href="page4.html">Menu2</a></li>

            <li><a href="page5.html">Menu3</a></li>

       </ul>
   </nav>
```